# CocoaLibSpotify Create playlists ending

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

I'm creating an IOS App based on cocoaLibSpotify.

In some point, I'm creating a Spotify playlist from an array of songs. I have previously obtained all the Spotify URIs and then I create the playlist and add all the tracks one by one.

The code below is in the logic class of the app and then I have a controller to show the results.
The problem is that I call this logic from the controller but I dont know the way to get back when the adding process has finished. I have tried to implement a delegate but im not sure how to do it...

Which is the right way to add tracks to a playlist? I have been searching on the documentation and in the GitHub repository but I have only found an example with two nested track addings... :S

Thanks in advance! (and sorry for my english)

```
- (void) createPlaylist:(NSArray*)spotifyURIs withName:(NSString*)name {

    int songsRead = 0;
    [container createPlaylistWithName:name callback:^(SPPlaylist *createdPlaylist) {

        [SPAsyncLoading waitUntilLoaded:createdPlaylist timeout:kSPAsyncLoadingDefaultTimeout then:^(NSArray *loadedPlaylist, NSArray *notLoadedPlaylist) {

            for (int i=[spotifyURIs count]-1; i>=0; i--) {

                NSString *trackURI = spotifyURIs[i];
                if (trackURI != nil){
                    [[SPSession sharedSession] trackForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:trackURI] callback:^(SPTrack *track) {
                        if (track != nil) {
                            [createdPlaylist addItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject: track] atIndex:[[createdPlaylist items] count] callback:nil];
                        }
                    }];
                }

                songsRead++;

                // If I have read the whole tracklist, end of the process, returning to controller...
                if (songsRead == [spotifyURIs count]){
                    // ...
                }
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to use the KVO system on your new playlist or using BLOCKS
you can implement something like this

typedef void (^spotifycompletionWithData)(id data);

-(void)addTrack:(NSString *)trackURI withCompletionBlock:(spotifycompletionWithData)CompletionBlock;

then whenever you call the function you should return the loaded SPTRACK within the completion block i hope its helping